# Ng-grid, customize grouping template with extra data

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Im using angular ng-grid to list my data and have activated grouping.
When I have grouped some data I would like to add an extra row under each group that aggregates the data in that group.

I have tried to alter the aggregate-template but I can't figure out how to add a row since every row has an absolute position.

Example:

Normal table without grouping

```
ID    Name    Euro    USD
1     Erik    10      45
2     Tom     10      14
3     John    67      78
```

This is how I want it to look like when grouping on Euro for example.

```
ID    Name    Euro    USD
> 10
3     NaN     -       59    * This is the extra row *
> 67
3     NaN     -       78    * This is the extra row *
```

Here is my aggregate-function that sums every group:

```
$scope.aggFunc = function (row, col) {
    var sumColumn = col;
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach(row.children, function(entry) {
        total+= parseInt(entry.entity[sumColumn]);
    });
    angular.forEach(row.aggChildren, function(entry) {
        total+= parseInt($scope.aggFunc(entry));
    });
    return total;
};
```

Here is the aggregate-template that currently aggregates on the same row:

```
<div ng-click="row.toggleExpand()" ng-style="rowStyle(row)" class="ngAggregate">
    <span class="ngAggregateText">{{row.label CUSTOM_FILTERS}} (Euro: {{aggFunc(row, 'Euro')}} USD: {{aggFunc(row, 'USD')}})</span>
    <div class="{{row.aggClass()}}"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks.